# How can I disable the Chrome update request?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, google-chrome

I have an embedded system with installed lubuntu 22.04 and Google-Chrome version 114.
When the system boot a script starts Chrome in kiosk mode.
In these last days (October 2023) Chrome shows the error message presented in the following pictures: [image]

In the last July the error was not showed.

The system is not connected to Internet and it is not expected the Google-Chrome is updated: it must remain at the version 114 without the need of any update for now.

How can I disable the Chrome update request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some google researches I have found a command line option for Google-Chrome `--simulate-outdated-no-au`. In this way Google-Chrome is started by the following command:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' --kiosk file:/path/to/my_start_page.html &
```

The option force Chrome to go **Out of date** on 31 Dec 2099 at 23:59:59 and this is enough to avoid the unwanted error message on boot.